# nginx redis\memcached modules gzip_flag

Tags: nginx, redis, memcached

both plugin seems to use the same code for [redis_gzip_flag](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/redis/#redis-gzip-flag) and  [memcached_gzip_flag](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_memcached_module.html#memcached_gzip_flag) not provide any instructions about this flag and how to set it, as redis string doesn't have any flag support

- so what is this flag?
- where I set it in redis?
- what number should I choose in the nginx config?

Answer (score 0):

Hadn't heard of this but I found an example [here](https://github.com/HoopCHINA/ngx_http_redis), looks like you add it manually to your location block when you know the data you're going to be requesting from redis is gzipped.

Comment: yes but you somehow need to create a flag in redis\memcached and there is no flag feature in both of them so I don't understand it